# Pass in a command string to AutoHotkey

Tags: powershell, autohotkey, process-substitution

I want to run a single AutoHotkey command. A script seems kindof overkill.

In bash and powershell, you can run a command by passing it in as a string to the shell:

```
pwsh -Command ls
bash -c ls
```

Is there a way to do this with AutoHotKey.exe? In the [documentation](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Scripts.htm#cmd), all I see is that you can pass the name of a script file to execute. If powershell supported process substitution `<(ls)`, I could do

```
AutoHotKey.exe <(echo "ls")
```

But I don't think there's a way to do this in powershell.

Is there another way other than [creating a complicated version of process substitution myself](https://serverfault.com/a/751293/405013)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [linked docs](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Scripts.htm#cmd) state:

> [v1.1.17+]: Specify an asterisk (`*`) for the filename to read the script text from standard input (stdin). For an example, see [ExecScript()](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Run.htm#ExecScript).

For instance, from PowerShell:

```
'MsgBox % "Hello, world."' | AutoHotKey.exe *
```

Comment: Thanks, this is the 3rd time I've run across your posts today :). For some reason it's taking several minutes for my commands to execute. I can see the several ahk processes hanging and then after several minutes all the msg boxes occur at once. I guess I'll open another question if needed.

Comment: @xdhmoore :) That's a strange symptom, which I didn't run into.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you're looking for what the other answer states, or then for this what I'm about to write:
You can pass arguments into an AHK script and those arguments are then found from the built in variable [`A_Args`](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Variables.htm#Args).

Example AHK script:

```
for each, arg in A_Args
    output .= arg "`n"
MsgBox, % output
```

PowerShell command:

```
& "C:\Path\To\My\Script.ahk" arg1 arg2 "this is the 3rd argument" arg4
```

This would be if you have AHK installed. If you have some portable AHK setup, you'd pass in the example script to AutoHotkey.exe and then the desired arguments.